# Is that possible when i am not live streaming in youtube . it will show my previous video?

Tags: youtube, streaming

Is it possible that whem i am not streaming in youtube it will show my previous video in my website that where i use embeded code

Answer (score -1):

No, you cannot do that however there are various ways by which you can show a video offline.

Comment: but in my site its showing streamin is off but i want to show previous video as my last stream

Comment: that is what i said, it is not possible to show your last streamed video on your website.

Comment: kindly check the green tick so that this answer is useful for others as well.